# Unable to create website error (NEW)

Tags: security, authentication, iis-6, publish

I copied my ClickOnce deployment to my C:/Inetpub/ folder on my webserver and I deleted my Virtual directory.  I deleted the WpfApplication1 folder beneath wwwroot in Win Explorer.  Then I turned on Web Sharing for this folder.  Then I viewed my IIS Manager and this new Share name appeared under wwwroot.

So now under Inetpub folder on my web server I have the following directory path:
C:\Inetpub\WpfApplication1\

with contents:
Application Files
publish.htm
setup.exe
WpfApplication1.application

Next, I remapped both the publishing and installation URL's for the project to http://myserver/WpfApplication1/
And I clicked Publish Now.

But after I performed a Publish Now operation, I got the following error on my development server (D610-M):

Error 1 Failed to connect to 'http://myserver/WpfApplication1/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'http://myserver/WpfApplication1/'.  The Web server does not appear to have any authentication methods enabled.  It asked for user authentication, but did not send a WWW-Authenticate header.  1 1 WpfApplication1
On my webserver, when I click Browse from the IIS Manager on the WpfApplication1 directory, it shows me the Install page.  But after I click the Browse button, it returns an error which says: 
The remote name could not be resolved: 'd610-m'  (D610-M is the name of my development server).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the IP address of the machine instead of the DNS name...